# How to find unique identifier for an android device?

Tags: android, unique

Sorry if the title is not adequate, but I couldn't think of what else to call it. Anyway, Iv'e been searching how to find a particular android id but   when I search "device ID android" or "android ID android", most solutions lead me to the ANDROID_ID which is "A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device".

I am trying to find another type of device ID (which I'm pretty sure is unique and doesn't change) which looks similar to this: android:36e32805-d44a-20fd-72dd-dc1366ec8a71.

Any help with finding this ID would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to get a UDID when using GCM?

Comment: This is not a simple question, but it's already been written about extensively, so any appropriate followup should go there in light of the history, not in a brand new question.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link - http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000103 . However in my opinion unique device ID can be obtained by combining imei , serial and Android ID , since each has its downside .